# VSCodeVim: How to change FG color for vscodevim command error messages

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

In VSCodeVim command mode, if I type an invalid command like `:random` , it throws an error in status bar like below.

[image]

My question is how do I change the Foreground color of these error messages. Any idea? 
I am not sure if this would be a setting of `VSCodeVim` or `VSCode` itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This color will depend on your theme. You can customize this with `statusBar` property in `workbench.colorCustomizations`

Documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#status-bar-colors

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#511f1f"
  }
}
```

You might have to do this for specific themes

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Some Theme Name]": {
        "statusBar.background" : "#486357",
        "statusBar.foreground" : "#c8e9c5",
     },
    "[Some Other Theme Name]": {
        "statusBar.background" : "#385357",
        "statusBar.foreground" : "#d7e9c4",
    }
},
```